# 3ds Max and Python

Tags: python-3.x, 3dsmax

I know that it is possible to create 3D objects and enviroments in python via using Pygame. But I wonder, if it is somehow possible to use the objects that you've created in 3ds Max within a python program. Because it seems that it takes a lot of time to code every detail in pygame to create 3D stuff.I think it would be easier if I could just use my mouse to draw objects just like in 3ds Max then to code every detail.Sorry if there are any gramattical mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3D is a world in itself - Pygame leverages 3D by providing some bindings to OpenGL -  which are themselves quite low level.

So, if you happen to findout a format that can be expoted by 3DS *and* canbe supported directly in a call to OpenGL, the answer to your question would be "yes".

But I doubt so - even if there are object formats directly usable by  OpenGL, you'd still have a tough time configuring the remainder of the scene.

The advice for you is to use a highr level binding to OpenGL, or  3D, and then check what formats are common between your binding (like [Python-Ogre](http://www.python-ogre.org/)) and the formats 3DS can export too.

My personal recommendation would be for you to use [Blender 3D](https://www.blender.org/) for your Python environment. Not only it embeds a full game engine 100% programable in Python, as it leverages tens of different file formats to import - and certainly will be hundreds of times (no exaggeration here - I mean more than one hundred times as easy as)  to code something like a finished game scene than using the raw OpenGL provided by Pygame.  Also, as you get used to Blender, you might start making part of your modeling in it as well, avoiding having to switch environments between Max and Blender.